# How does the WinForms MouseWheel event work in F#?

Tags: winforms, f#, mousewheel

I want to figure out how the mouseWheel event works in the winforms library.

Though there is never any good examples to learn when it comes to `F#`

I hope one of you guys can tell me.

i was thinking something like this:

```
 onMouseWheelEvent =
      if MouseWheel event = scroll forward then
        printfn "zooming in"
      else 
        printfn "zooming out"
```

I know it is some silly code i am posting but i literally cant find anything on the winforms mousewheelevent other than it exists. How it works remains a mystery.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the same examples you found for other languages. The syntax may be slightly different but it's still the same .NET Framework. The same event handlers work across all languages.

Comment: "*i literally cant find anything on the winforms mousewheelevent other than it exists. How it works remains a mystery.*" As usual, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx#Remarks) is a good place to start...

Comment: I would challenge the assumption that winforms is a particularly good playground for learning F# (or any other new language, for that matter). For learning F#, I'd focus on core concepts like functions, data structures, immutability, F# library functions. There's quite some room to improve the code quality in the code you've recently posted in other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running this in f# interactive (courtesy of a similar example on [fssnip from Tomas Petricek](http://fssnip.net/p/title/Form-changing-color)):

```
open System.Windows.Forms

// Create form, label and add label to form
let form = new Form(Text = "Scroller Test")
let label = new Label()
form.Controls.Add(label)

// register mousewheel event handler and capture scrolling
form.MouseWheel.Add(fun e -> 
    match e.Delta with
    | n when n > 0 -> label.Text <- "Scrolled up"
    | n when n < 0 -> label.Text <- "Scrolled down"
    | _ -> ()) // making compiler happy even though e.Delta cannot be 0

// Show the form (in F# Interactive)
form.Show()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using F# interactive, the simplest thing you can write to test how the `MouseWheel` event behaves is something like this:

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let frm = new Form(Visible=true)
frm.MouseWheel.Add(fun e ->
  printfn "%A" e.Delta
)
```

When you select the code and send it to F# Interactive (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in most F# editors), you should see a form appear. When you then scroll, you'll see that `Delta` is negative or postivie number indicating how much up or down you scrolled.

If you want to run this as a standalone application, you'll need to display the numbers elsewhere (using a label, I guess) and you'll need to add `Application.Run(frm)` to the end to start the application.

I'd agree with Anton that WinForms is perhaps not what most people use for developing user interface applications these days, but I think that's not a problem - you can use WinForms to build perfectly fine applications and learn F#.  The [F# book I wrote some time ago](https://www.manning.com/petricek) has a bunch of WinForms examples.